# Extract function argument sequence

Tags: function-construction, sequence

Is it somehow possible to access and reference the sequence of arguments of a non-pure function?

For example if I want to take the derivative with respect to the n'th argument, a pseudocode example would be:

```
DiffNthArg[fun_,n_]:=D[fun,(*code for nth argument*)]

DiffNthArg[f[x,y,z],3]
Out[]: D[f[x,y,z],z]
```

I read that the one can extract the sequence of the function arguments by the following code: `f /. f[z__]:>z`
Therefore one could use the following:

```
DiffNthArg[fun_,n_]:=D[fun, fun /. g_[z__] :> List[z][[n]] ]
```

**BUT:** This only works on undefined functions. If I apply it to already defined functions, the applied pattern will be applied to the *already evaluated* function, and thus does not return the list of function arguments.

For example, if I previously define `f` the following way, `DiffNthArg` will take the derivative with respect to c, not z:

```
f[x_,y_,z_]:= a b c z
DiffNthArg[f,3]
Out[]: a b z
```

How do I get the "original" argument sequence of the unevaluated function (even if it is already defined before)?

Comment: You probably want to add some form of Hold attribute to the definition of your function. It may be helpful to add a specific example.

Comment: I thought, I added two examples already (one how it should behave and one how it actually behaves). The problem is, that once defined, `f` will be substituted by its defined expression (`a b c z`) no matter which kind of `Hold` I wrap around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
g[a_,b_,c_]:= a b c + 2 a + 1

(* the [[1, 1]] gets the signature of f, 
   while the [[All, 1]] gets the symbol from the list of Pattern-s *)
argList[f_] := 
 ReleaseHold[DownValues[f][[1, 1]] /. {f -> List}][[All, 1]]

argList[g]
(** {a, b, c} **)

D[ g[a,b,c], argList[g][[3]] ]
(** a b **)
```

Comment: Brilliant, this works as intended! For some reason I thought there might be a more direct way of accessing function arguments which I just couldn't find in the documentation. But this way is just as fine as well.

Comment: Ok, so there is one more question I have: Upon implementation, I realized that I could for example __not__ do `DFirst[f_] := D[f, argList[f][[1]]]`.
So if I define `g[x,y]:=x+y`, I would get `DFirst[g[x,y]] --> 0`. Why is that? Because `argList` needs as argument `g` but not `g[x,y]`. So when calling `DFirst`, instead of `g` being passed, `x+y` is passed to `argList`. Is there a way around that?

Comment: @jabberwocky `g[x,y]` is the result of applying g to x,y, so what you're asking doesn't make much sense.  You should do `DFirst[g]` instead. Also define `g[x_, y_] := x + y` not `g[x,y]:=x+y` - otherwise you'd need to change `argList` to `argList[f_]:=ReleaseHold[DownValues[f][[1, 1]] /. f -> List]` if not using patterns (x_, y_)

Comment: Ah I see, that makes sense. So writing `DFirst[f_] := D[f[argList[f] /. List -> Sequence], argList[f][[1]]]` will work as expected. Thanks for the clarification!